# Using Roth and Rollover IRA for home down payment

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, rollover, penalty

I'm not able to find anything on this.  I'm planning to withdraw $5000 from my Roth IRA and $5000 from my Rollover IRA for a home down payment.  That's the $10k max to avoid a 10% penalty.

But does the $10k max apply to each type of IRA or just any type of IRAs in aggregate?  In other words, can I do $10k from a Roth and $10k from the Rollover?

Comment: You can always withdraw your nominal annual contributions from your Roth IRA for any reason.  I understand for the purpose of the $10,000 qualified withdrawl for a "first time home purchase", you first must withdraw all contributions before you withdraw the $10,000 in earnings.  However, I don't know enough about the questions around the rollover to attempt a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

$10,000 is the limit across any and all IRAs, including Roth. $10,000 Total, not per account.